# Regex to validate URL hash not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code for checking the URL hash part and extract the query strings.

```
var getCleanHash = function(){
    return (/^[a-z-_&=\d]*$/.test(location.hash.substr(1))) ? location.hash.substr(1) : "";
}
```

so the regex used here is `/^[a-z-_&=\d]*$/`, but if I have the query strings like `type=mytype&q=search`, it is returning empty value. If I remove the `^` from the regex, it starts returning the query strings. But then it will not perform any checks as intended in regex. I suppose `^` denotes the first character, but not entirely sure why it doesn't match with my query string part.

Can someone help me to find what this Regex actually means and how can I fix the issue with empty query strings?

Comment: `/^[a-z-_&=\d]*$/.test("type=mytype&q=search")` returns `true`?

Comment: yeah. But sometimes, my search string will be two words separated by `+` like `q=search+string`

Comment: Your regex would work if you can remove the URL pre-leading...

Comment: okay. Actually, how can I accommodate the `+` sign. If there is the `+` sign, which is substituted when there is whitespace, the regex is false.

Comment: and also I don't want to specify the case. Currently, it is taking only lowercase

Comment: @Happy What does `\w` mean in regex?  Also, do we get to see a small battery of test cases and desired outputs? ...as part of a [mcve]?

Comment: post the full url that you want to test... starting from https:// and everything till the end.

Answer (score 0):

var getCleanHash = function(){

```
return (/^[a-z\d\-_&\=]*$/.test(location.hash.substring(1))) ? location.hash.substring(1) : "";
```

}

I think you should use .substring(1) instead of .substr(1)
[a-z\d-_&=]* means you are testing:

- for any hash even empty ones on the entire length(from start ^ to end $)
- a to z and digits plus the following characters(-_&=)

Comment: location.hash returns the anchor part of a URL. Assume that the current URL is http://www.doregex.com/test.htm#part2 it will return #part2.

Comment: If you want to access the query string instead of location.hash.substring(1) you should use location.href.split('?').slice(1).join('?')